# Using the dart:js library without a html file

Tags: javascript, proxy, dart, dart-js-interop

Is it possible to use the dart:js library without having a html file to load the js files but some alternative way of loading the javascripts in the context?

I need this for a command-line app, so having a html file makes no sense

Comment: No experience in it myself, but is it https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/contents/ch04-tools-dart-vm.html you are looking for?

Comment: That explains how to run apps from command-line, not how to use the dart:js lib from a command-line-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run a command line app in the DartVM there is no Javascript VM, so you cannot use Javascript libraries.

However depending on your use case, you could run your javascript code with node.js, and communicate with the DartVM using sockets.

Perhaps add some more details about your specific use case.

**Update:**

To run lessc from Dart, first install node.js.

Then Install lessc:

```
npm install -g less
lessc styles.less styles.css
```

You can then call lessc from Dart using dart:io [Process.run()](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_io/Process.html#run).

Comment: I'm trying to compile less stylesheets to css using the existing js library

Comment: Thanks, I guess that answered mu question

Comment: No problem. Just saw that there is a sass library on pub which works like this too. You could probably re-use some code from there. http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/sass  https://bitbucket.org/evidentsolutions/dart-sass/src/b5c4886a73488fa827dcdde90acd075ce6d9b2ef/lib/sass.dart?at=master